# How can I filter List property

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

On my View I have a AutoSuggestBox(searchfield) and ListView, my ListView's ItemSource is bounded to my VM Class property:

```
private Class1 _searchMatches;
public Class1 SearchMatches {
    get { return _searchMatches; }
    set { this.Set(ref _searchMatches, value); }
}
```

On My Class1 I have a LoadItems Task:

async Task> LoadItems()

```
var stocks = _response.products?
                .Select(s => new MyClass(PLService.DtoToModel(s)))
                .ToList();
        var items = stocks.GroupBy(p => p.productModel.Description)
                                .Select(p => p.First())
                                .ToList();
        return items;
```

When i type *test* on the AutoSuggestBox and hit enter, What is the simplest way to filter items where(item.description == searchterm)?
just filter it and update itemsource, not rewriting the property

Comment: Why not filter on the datasource of the filter, and apply the result as datasource on the ListView?

Comment: can you please provide code?

Comment: well if stocks is a ObservableCollection then you need to copy it to a temporary variable clear the original collection and then re-add the filtered items to your source observable collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<SearchBox>` and it's `QuerySubmitted` event. But it will work well with `<TextBox>` too. 
If you need to *refilter* your `Items` - just create two lists, one to store your `Items` and another for items displaying.

Here is a `<SearchBox>` sample:

```
private List<MyClass> _items; // store for your items

private List<MyClass> _displayItems;
public List<MyClass> DisplayItems // list to show
{
    get { return _displayItems; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _displayItems, value); }
}

private void SearchBoxQuerySubmitted(SearchBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   searchTerm = eventArgs.QueryText?.Trim();
   Filter(searchTerm);
}

private void Filter(string searchTerm)
{
   if (_items == null)
       return;

   IQueryable<MyClass> items = _items.AsQueryable();

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
   {
      searchTerm = searchTerm.ToLower();
      items = items.Where(x => x.productModel.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm));
   }

   DisplayItems = items.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Im sorry , but iam using autosuggest so there is querrysubmitted , but am I able to recover old items on that , i mean if my Class count is 20 , then after filter became 7 , when search for other searchterm , will it search for 20 items instead of the filtered items?

Comment: And yes, it will search in 20 items, because you make query and create new list, it's not changing original `_items`