# UWP ListView grouping one group at the time

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I want to make listview that will show only one group at the time.
I know how to create groups with items under it like in this picture:

[image]

I want to have only header items visible, and when user clicks on some header, all items from that group will be shown, and on the top there will be Back button to return to headers.

I have created 2 listviews, in one there are headers and in second list there are group items, and I switch the visibility of them. This works great, but I want to use groups possibilities.

Any hint on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter each list when you clicking the list item. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363486/how-can-i-filter-list-property) you can find how make list filter.

And handle `ItemClick`  for each list

```
private void OnCouchItemClick(ItemClickEventArgs obj)
    {
        Couch item = obj?.ClickedItem as Couch;
        itemsAreFiltered = true;
        if (item != null)
            Filter(item);
    }
```

And handle back button press:

```
private bool itemsAreFiltered;

private async void OnGoBack()
{
    if (itemsAreFiltered)
    {
        itemsAreFiltered = false;
        RefreshListsToDefault();
    }
    else
        // go back
}
```

Comment: No, I don't need like that. I need the list to be switched to show only items from selected group.

Comment: You need to filter each list by selected item value? Filter players by selected couch and filter couches by selected player?

Comment: Yes. And on the top there will be BACK button that will remove that filter and show only headers.

Comment: In this case you should handle list items and back button clicking to filter tour items. I refactored my answer